# Laravel5 event 'deleting' doesn't work on Model::whereIn()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have one to many relation on the user model, I have set an event when I delete the user will dell all Childs `client`.
on the resource, the Controller destroys method event 'deleting' method is work for normally.

But I create a mass massDestroy method using `Model::whereIn()` `deleting` event doesn't work.

Below is my related code, How can I fix it?

`UsersController` relate code

```
public function destroy(User $user)
{
    $user->delete();

    return back();
}

public function massDestroy(MassDestroyUserRequest $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        User::whereIn('id', $request->get('ids'))->delete();
    }

    return response(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
}
```

User Model relate code

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes, Notifiable;

    public $table = 'users';

    //skip

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::deleting(function (User $user) {
           $user->clients()->delete(); //doesn't work on Model::whereIn
        });
    }

    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Client::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Client model relate code

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class ,'user_id', 'id');
}
```

PS* I have try to delete one by one( very ugly code ) as below is normally work.

`UsersController`

```
public function massDestroy(MassDestroyUserRequest $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
            $users = User::whereIn('id', $request->get('ids'))->get();
            foreach ($users as $user ) {
                $user ->delete();
            }
    }

    return response(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
}
```

Comment: you are calling `delete` on a builder not the `delete` method on a model instance, there are no events fired when you bypass the model by directly calling a delete query like this because there are no model instances returned ... you can use the `destroy` method on the model and pass it multiple ids and it will get them and call delete on them for you ... this is pointed out in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly stated in laravel documentation that if you need to perform mass operations then none of the events will be fired. You need to delete them one by one using `foreach`.

> When executing a mass delete statement via Eloquent, the `deleting` and `deleted` model events will not be fired for the deleted models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when executing the delete statement.

Please check note option in [Deleting Models](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#deleting-models)

Answer (score 1):

You are using function `get()` to retrieve a collection of records and there is no method `delete()` on collection, either you delete by using `first()` function or delete them by looping the collection array.

I hope you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

I have a trick for your problem

It is clearly stated in [Laravel documentation Deleting Models](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#deleting-models) that if you need to perform mass operations then none of the events will be fired.

> When executing a mass delete statement via Eloquent, the `deleting` and `deleted` model events will not be fired for the deleted models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when executing the delete statement.

My Trick is:

Use this code

```
$ids = User::whereIn('id', $request->get('ids'))->pluck('id');
User::destroy($ids);
```

instead of

```
//User::whereIn('id', $request->get('ids'))->delete();
```